How to write a formula pulling data from multiple cells and drop down options
I really tried reviewing other answers that seemed similar but I just couldn't get it to do what I needed. I need to create a daily/weekly total of our sales in multiple divisions. I have a table, w/ drop downs for ea division i need to pull the data from and have it plug into a smaller table. I imagine i need to use an "if" formula but i need help!
Example:
If it's Mon/Tue/Wed...(column A)
and the division is Jacksonville/tampa/orl...(drop down column B)
I need the amount (column F) to populate in the cell related in the bottom table
Right now, I am manually typing in the total amounts per day/division and have a basic formula set up to total each division day and week. I hope this makes sense enough to help me!
enter image description here

Complex formulae with many conditions are more easily in SQL on a database than for a spreadsheet. Consider using a DB such as MS Access, which is part of MS Office, free LibreOffice Base, or one of the many alternatives.

A PivotTable (or two, or more as fits your needs), or a bunch of SUMIF functions seem like a good starting point for a solution here

Instead of duplicating the data from a data entry table to another table, consider creating a report on the data in the data entry table.
You could create pivot tables and use slicers or filters to show only the days and divisions you are interested in. Create a pivot table for each division, for example. Or, you could use dynamic array formulas (Filter(),Sort(),Unique(), etc.) combined with Xlookup() to construct lookups into the data entry table.
Duplicating the data via manual operations or VBA is the least desirable approach.
